# How do I combine two conditions on a Mysql Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my db.
First

> account_type

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Sr_No  | Key 1       | Key 2    |   Key 3  |  Key 4   |    Key 5 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       |  Person 1   | Person 1 | Person 1 | Person 1 | Person 1 |
| 2       |  Null       |    NULL  | Person 2 | Person 2 | Person 2 | 
| 3       |  Person 2   |    NULL  | Person 3 | NULL     | Null     | 
| 4       |  Null       |    NULL  | NULL     | NULL     | Person 4 | 
| 5       |  Null       |    NULL  | NULL     | Person 5 | Person 5 | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> branch

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  Sr_No  | Bangalore   | Hyderabad|   Chennai|
-----------------------------------------------
| 1       |  Person 1   | Person 1 | Person 1 |
| 2       |  Null       |    NULL  | Person 2 | 
| 3       |  Person 2   |    NULL  | Person 3 | 
| 4       |  Null       |    NULL  | NULL     | 
| 5       |  Null       |    NULL  | NULL     | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

> cust_code

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| Cust_code | Name      | Address   |   Branch |   Type      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| A9999     | Company 1 | Address 1 | Bangalore|  MJA        |
| B672      | Company 2 | Address 2 | Chennai  |  Govt       |
| Z233      | Company 3 | Address 3 | Hyderabad|  KSA        | 
| Q1111     | Company 4 | Address 4 | Bangalore|  Key Account| 
| I665      | Company 1 | Address 5 | Chennai  |  KSA        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

First of all Bangalore, hyderabad and chennai are places
I have a requirement such that a person should be able to search for only those cust_codes whose branch should match with his columns in branch table and at the same time only those customer codes should be visible who match with the account_type . Like Person 5  whos account type is key1 and key2 and his branch is bangalore and chennai should only search for cust_codes whos branches are bangalore or chennai and the type is key1 and key2.

I was able to do the branch query using if else loop in php. But at the same time I have to filter out the types as well.

The code I tried to filter out the location is

```
$bangalore="Bangalore";
$hyderabad="Hyderabad";
$chennai="Chennai";
$sess_uname="bmw";
$qry_bangalore=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_branch where Bangalore='$sess_uname'");
$count_bangalore=mysql_num_rows($qry_bangalore);

$qry_hyderabad=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_branch where Hyderabad='$sess_uname'");
$count_hyderabad=mysql_num_rows($qry_hyderabad);

$qry_chennai=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_branch where Chennai='$sess_uname'");
$count_chennai=mysql_num_rows($qry_chennai);

$qry_keyaccount=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_acctype where `Key Account`='$sess_uname'");
$count_keyaccount=mysql_num_rows($qry_keyaccount);

$qry_runrate=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_acctype where Runrate='$sess_uname'");
$count_runrate=mysql_num_rows($qry_runrate);

$qry_mja=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_acctype where MJA='$sess_uname'");
$count_mja=mysql_num_rows($qry_mja);

$qry_govt=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_acctype where Govt='$sess_uname'");
$count_govt=mysql_num_rows($qry_govt);

$qry_kso=mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name_acctype where KSO='$sess_uname'");
$count_kso=mysql_num_rows($qry_kso);


if($count_bangalore!=0 && $count_hyderabad!=0 && $count_chennai!=0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%' order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_bangalore==0 && $count_hyderabad!=0 && $count_chennai!=0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch<>'$bangalore' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_hyderabad==0 && $count_bangalore!=0 && $count_chennai!=0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch<>'$hyderabad' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_chennai==0 && $count_bangalore!=0 && $count_hyderabad!=0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch<>'$chennai' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_bangalore==0 && $count_hyderabad==0 && $count_chennai!=0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch=='$chennai' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_bangalore==0 && $count_hyderabad!=0 && $count_chennai==0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch=='$hyderabad' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
elseif($count_bangalore!=0 && $count_hyderabad==0 && $count_chennai==0)
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch=='$bangalore' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
else
    $qr="select Cust_code,Cust_Name,Cust_City from mgen_custcode where Mgen_branch=='America' AND (Cust_Name like '%$q%' or Cust_code like '%$q%') order by Cust_Name";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your datebase structure will not allow this you need to change this
create new table with the city name and id save your city in that table and create an other table with city_branch save your ids and city detail then your join will work

Comment: I know the database structure is very bad. I joined in a new firm and I m adding new module to a pre existing site. I don't have option to change table structure. Is there anything which can be done?? Using if else maybe??